# Python re.search for multiple values in the same line

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I am trying to use re.search (or re.findall) to interpret a line, and change the keyword by a value.

My example string is:

```
line = 'Text1 <<ALTER, variable = Ion1>> Text2 <<ALTER, variable = Value1>>\n'
```

With values of `Ion1` of 'Na' and `Value1` of 1.0, I would like to have the return of

```
processedline = 'Text1 Na Text2 1.0'
```

To do so, I tryed the following code:

```
result = re.search('<<ALTER(.*)>>', line)
aux_txt = result.group(1).split('=')
var = aux_txt[-1].strip()
value = ParameterDictionary[var]
processedline = re.sub('<<ALTER(.*)>>', str(value), line, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

However, the return I am getting, for the variable `result`, is `', variable = Ion1>> Text2 <<ALTER, variable = Value1'`, i.e., it does not treat independently both keywords.

Anyone has some idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modify your `.*` (which is greedy) to `.*?` i.e. non-greedy to match shortest string possible. See the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html?highlight=greedy#repeating-things

Answer (score 1):

That is because your regex is matching the entire string (till last `>>`) instead of matching till the first occurrence of `>>` after `Ion1`. You need to use `lazy` operator with your `.*` to limit the match.

What `.*?` does is this: It matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

Here is an example with an explanation: https://regex101.com/r/oKyOIn/1

Answer (score 1):

*Python re.search for multiple values in the same line*

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is wrong tool for this task, it does return first (leftmost) match or `None` if not match was found. You should use either [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) which gives iterator of Match objects or [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) which gives `list` of `str`s or `tuple`s.

Also as already noted you need to change your pattern `<<ALTER(.*)>>` as it does match too much, you might use non-greedy version i.e.

```
<<ALTER(.*?)>>
```

or if `>` is not allowed inside `<<` and `>>` harness that as follows

```
<<ALTER([^>]*)>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using groups to capture within `re.sub` seems to be what you are looking for. `re.sub` accepts a function as the `repl` (replacement string argument). The function is evaluated with the match object as argument. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

```py
>>> param_dict = {'Ion1': 'Na', 'Variable1': '1.0'}
>>> re.sub(r'<<ALTER, variable = ([\w\d]+)>>', lambda m: param_dict[m.group(1)], line)
'Text1 Na Text2 1.0\n'
```

The regex group `([\w\d]+)` can be adapted to the kind of values you expect to find.

Using raw strings (starting with r') for regexes in python is good practice and can save you from headaches.

Comment: Edited to replace with values from dictionary. `re.sub` accepts a function as the `repl` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture one or more word characters (alphanumeric including underscores) inside `<<ALTER, variable =` and `>>`, and then use a callable in the `re.sub` method replacement argument:

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oGx2mJ):

```py
import re
ParameterDictionary = {'Ion1': 'Na', 'Value1': '1.0'}
line = 'Text1 <<ALTER, variable = Ion1>> Text2 <<ALTER, variable = Value1>>\n'
rx = r'<<ALTER, variable = (\w+)>>'
result = re.sub(rx, lambda x: ParameterDictionary.get(x.group(1), x.group()), line)
print(result)
# => Text1 Na Text2 1.0
```

Here,

- `<<ALTER, variable = (\w+)>>` matches `<<ALTER, variable =`, space, then `(\w+)` captures into Group 1 any one or more word chars and then `>>` is matched
- The match is passed into `re.sub` within a lambda expression, as `x`, and the `ParameterDictionary.get(x.group(1), x.group())` either returns the corresponding value by found key, or the whole match (`x.group()`).

Answer (score 0):

Using `.*` is too broad, and capture everything between `<<ALTER` and `>>`. Why not use a more specific regexp ?

```
>>> re.findall(r"<<ALTER, variable = (\w+)>>", line)
['Ion1', 'Value1']
```

Comment: [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269183/3832970) does not need to extract the matches, but replace them with the values from a dictionary. See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269901/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!
It worked perfectly like this:

```
import re

ParameterDictionary = {'Ion1': 'Na', 'Value1': '1.0'}
line = 'Text1 <<ALTER, variable = Ion1>> Text2 <<ALTER, variable = Value1>>\n'
result = re.findall(r'<<ALTER, variable = (\w+)>>', line)
for txt in result:
    aux_txt = f'<<ALTER, variable = {txt}>>'
    value = ParameterDictionary[txt]
    line = re.sub(aux_txt, str(value), line, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: There is no need to perform so many regex searches. All you need is a single call to `re.sub` and parse the text with regex only once, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269901/3832970)